# Javascript findindex performance issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having an array as like this

```
var projectItemList=[{
    "id":1,
    "projectid":"a0I3l00001YiS67EAF",
    "date":"2021-06-18",
    "task":"",
    "starttime":"",
    "endtime":"",
    "description":"",
    "hours":"",
    "projectname":"MyCOmp1",
    "computedclass":"lookupclass1"
}, {
    "id":1,
    "projectid":"a0I3l00001YiS67EAF",
    "date":"2021-06-18",
    "task":"",
    "starttime":"",
    "endtime":"",
    "description":"",
    "hours":"",
    "projectname":"Myproject",
    "computedclass":"lookupclass1"
}];
```

and this array grows with n number of rows and I am pushing the dynamic constructed rows to the above array by incrementing the id.

and depending on keystroke I am changing the description of objects by finding the index and I am using this method to find the index

```
findIndex(id) {    
    return this.projectItemList.findIndex((obj => obj.id == id));
}
```

```
this.projectItemList[this.findIndex(id)].description ='xxxxxxx'
```

If the array length is 5 then things are fine. If the array grows more than 10, say 50 or 100
then its taking some delay to find the index and causing the issue.

I tried with many options but still same issue

```
return this.projectItemList.map(function(x) {           
    return (x.id);             
}).indexOf(id);
```

How to overcome this performance issue?

Comment: you may want to look at some alternative which provide constant time lookup.. such as map object

Comment: Just index your objects by `id` and then get them directly by the index `projectItems[id]` (or `projectItems.get(id)` if you use a Map). That way you don't have to search for them every time.

Comment: Would you provide an actual example that shows the *slowing*? 50 or even 100 array items doesn't look like much.

Comment: @VLAZ Not getting your answer, can u plz help?

Comment: @Yoshi , actually I am using this for dynamically adding a row. So if i add 100 row then 100 text area boxes will be rendered, so onchange of that text area I am finding the exact row and changing the description

Comment: Ok, so for example the 100th textarea corresponds to the 100th array item? If so, why even do the lookup? You already have the index?

Comment: @Yoshi , sorry My bad the performance issue is because of looping the array in UI. 110 times text area is looping and trying to set the value. I wrongly misjudged the place. Thnk you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the structure of the array, you can run `find` method for the array.

```js
var projectItemList = [{
    "id":1,
    "projectid":"a0I3l00001YiS67EAF",
    "date":"2021-06-18",
    "task":"",
    "starttime":"",
    "endtime":"",
    "description":"",
    "hours":"",
    "projectname":"MyCOmp1",
    "computedclass":"lookupclass1"
}, {
    "id":2,
    "projectid":"a0I3l00001YiS67EAF",
    "date":"2021-06-18",
    "task":"",
    "starttime":"",
    "endtime":"",
    "description":"",
    "hours":"",
    "projectname":"Myproject",
    "computedclass":"lookupclass1"
}];


const findIndex = id => projectItemList.find(i => i.id === id);

findIndex(1).description = 'bar';

console.log(projectItemList);
```

The complexity will be `n`, where `n` is the number of items in the array.

But the best solution, in my opinion, is changing your data to something like:

```
var list = {
    1: {
        name: 'name for 1',
        description: 'description for 1',
    },
    2: {
        name: 'name for 2',
        description: 'description for 2',
    }
};
```

from where, you can find the item like

```
list[1];
```

in 1 step.